# Typo3 Bootstrap Elements permissions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, permissions, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I would like to set up a user group which has permissions to insert the Bootstrap content elements on pages (e.g. Bootstrap: Column Row, Bootstrap: Button Link ...), I cannot find these permissions anywhere.
I am using Typo3 6.2.4 Bootstrap Package, which includes `Fluid Content: Twitter Bootstrap Elements` (fluidcontent_bootstrap) 
Any ideas?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general your user group should have the correct rights to list and edit page content. Furthermore you have to make the following changes to your user group:

1. Edit your user group
2. Go to the tab *Access Lists*
3. Make changes to the section *Allowed excludefields* (enable checkbox)

   - Page Content: Fluid Content type (tx_fed_fcefile)
4. Make changes to the section *Explicitly allow/deny field values* (enable checkbox)

   - [Allow] Fluid Content

And by the way: It's TYPO3 not Typo3 ;)